# Can't Read plist File

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I am having trouble reading the data in a plist file. I'm not getting the titleString printed in the console like I'm expecting. What am I doing wrong?[image]

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Events" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictPri = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *arrEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictPri valueForKey:@"Root"]];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrEvents)
    {
        NSString *titleString = nil;
        NSString *date = nil;
        titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Title"]];
        date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"Date"]];

        NSLog(@"Title String: %@", titleString);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main element (Root) is Dictionary - not Array - change it in plist by clicking on type next to it.

Also there is a problem in your code - you never access "Root" element by name - it's by default top-level object. Consider taking out additional array initialization which is not required.

Fixed code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Events" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* arrEvents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrEvents)
{
    NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Date"]];

    NSLog(@"Title String: %@", titleString);
}
```

Comment: I left Root as a dictionary and created an array within root and added items to that array.  Thanks!